# PHP Javascript Show/Hide button not working

Tags: php, javascript

This is my php code:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
$query="select title,content from blogs";
echo '<html><head>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="blog.css" />';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="blog.js"></script></head><body>';
$i=0;
if($result=$mysqli->query($query))
{
while($news=$result->fetch_row())
{
echo "<br /><br /><strong>". $news[0]."</strong><br /><br />";
if(strlen($news[1])>60)
{
    $d=0;
    $content=explode(" ",$news[1]);
    foreach($content as $c)
    {
        if($d<=60)
        {
            echo $c." ";
            $d++;
        }
        else
        {
            if($d==61)
            {

                echo "<div id=a$i style='visibility:hidden'>";
                echo "<a href='#' onclick='toggle(a".$i.")' style='visibility:visible'>Show/Hide</a>";

                $i++;

                $d++;
            }
            echo $c." ";
            $d++;
            if($d==count($content)+1)
            {
                echo "</div>";
            }

        }


    }
}
else
echo $news[1]."<br /><br />";

}
$result->close();
echo "</body></html>";

}
?>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
function toggle(id)
{

    //document.getElementById('mcontent').value=x++;
    //if(x%2==0)
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility="visible";
    //else
    //document.getElementById('mcontent').style.visibility="hidden";
};
```

The show hide button is not working.My strategy is to limit text which contains more than 60 words with the show hide button.Once the user clicks the button the hidden div becomes visible and that contains the extra text(namely the text after 60 word count).Div element should always start with a letter so I have append letter 'a' before that.Please help me fix this.

Note:
**Don't need Jquery solutions or suggestion.I need only to debug the above code.**

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? Kan you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't get any error when I click the show/hide button the page reloads but doesn't show the remaining text.I can't provide JSFiddle because mysql fetches the data.

Comment: When you have this kind of bug, the first thing to do is to remove the PHP part and use fake hard-coded data.

Comment: My problem is fixed.Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing quotes in your call to `toggle`.

This would call `toggle(a0)` instead of `toggle("a0")`.

Try this :

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"toggle('a".$i."')\" style='visibility:visible'>Show/Hide</a>";
```

As I always find painful to deal with this level of imbricated quotes, I prefer to avoid inlined javascript in PHP. You can defer the addition of handlers even without jQuery, using `document.getElementById('...').onclick=...`.

Answer (score 2):

The `onclick` attribute on this line:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='toggle(a".$i.")' style='visibility:visible'>Show/Hide</a>";
```

...needs to have double-quotes around the parameter to `toggle()` so that the browser receives it as `onclick='toggle("a1")'`:

```
echo "<a href='#' onclick='toggle(\"a".$i."\")' style='visibility:visible'>Show/Hide</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<div id='a" . $i . "' style='visibility:hidden'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter in `toggle(a".$i.")` is a string. You should add string delimiters.
And also, you should add quotes to your attributes in yout HTML tags:

```
echo '<div id="' . a$i . '" style="visibility:hidden">';
```